# Accessing multiple Values from URI / QueryString

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2

How can I handle following request:

`/api/{controller}/{id_A}/{id_B}/?param1=value1&param2=value2...`

In my Controller I want to Access all variables:

- id_A
- id_B
- param1
- param2

All variables are simple types (strings and decimals).
What should I write into my Controller and in the WebApiConfig?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add them as parameters in your action method:

```
 public class MyController
 {
      public ActionResult MyAction(int id_A, string param1,...)
      {
           // your controller logic
      }
 }
```

Model binding takes care of everything.